# automatically new list can generated while sorting the lists with numbering

Tags: javascript, jquery

when i sort lists with each other sometime arround sorting new list generated. in this i can drag and drop into list in this i fill numeric in title and when sorting it can make new list..... i have to solve it... i have to just do is that it can properly sort and cannot make automatically new list
and work in reverse numeric order like (1,2,3) when sort it can in reverse order

```
   var start=1;
   function hideblocks(id){
//document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
$("#" + id).closest('li').remove();
//$("#" + id).closest('li').html('');
    }
    var default_title='Title goes here';
   var default_subtitle='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet';
   var text_boxes=new Array();

  var li_ids_to_start_from=2;

    $(window).load(function(){
$(".draggable li").draggable({
    appendTo: 'body',
    helper: 'clone',
});

function handle_drop(){
    $("#droppable li").droppable({
        hoverClass: "droppable-hovered",
        activeClass:"droppable-hovered-active",
        drop: function(event,ui) {
             +ui.draggable.parent().attr('id') + ' was dropped from ' + ui.draggable.parent().attr('id'));

            var dropped_to_html=$(this).html();
            var dropped_from_html=$("#" + ui.draggable.parent().attr('id')).html();


            var current_li_array=new Array();
            var li_array_index=0;
            $("#droppable").find('li').each(function(j, li){
                current_li_array[li_array_index]=$(this).attr('id');
                li_array_index++;
            })

            if(dropped_to_html !='' && ui.draggable.parent().attr('id') === undefined){

                var dropped_li=$(this).attr('id');

                $numeric_array=dropped_li.split('_');
                var current_li=$numeric_array[1];

                for(j=(current_li_array.length-1);j > current_li_array.indexOf(dropped_li);j--){
                    $("#" + current_li_array[j]).html($("#" + current_li_array[j -1]).html());
                    $("#" +current_li_array[j]).children(":first").attr('style','');

                    $("#" + current_li_array[j -1]).html('');

                    if(j==0){
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }

            if(ui.draggable.attr('id') !== undefined ){

                var dropped_to=$(this).attr('id');
                var split_id_dropped_to=dropped_to.split('_');

                var dropped_from=$("#" + ui.draggable.parent().attr('id')).attr('id');
                var split_id_dropped_from=dropped_from.split('_');


                if(dropped_to != dropped_from){



                    if(split_id_dropped_from > split_id_dropped_to){
                        $("#" + ui.draggable.parent().attr('id')).html('');
                    }



                    for(j=(current_li_array.length-1);j > current_li_array.indexOf(dropped_to);j--){

                        $("#" + current_li_array[j]).html($("#" + current_li_array[j -1]).html());
                        $("#" +current_li_array[j]).children(":first").attr('style','');


                        $("#" + current_li_array[j -1]).html('');

                        if(j==0){
                            break;
                        }
                    }


                    $(this).html(dropped_from_html);

                    if(split_id_dropped_from < split_id_dropped_to){
                        $("#" + ui.draggable.parent().attr('id')).closest('li').remove();
                    }
                }

            }else{
                if(ui.draggable.attr("class") =="letmego ui-draggable"){
                    $(this).html("<div  id=\"outhide"+ start+"\"><div class=\"drag_icon_out\"><div class=\"list_box\"><div class=\"cam_out\"><span><img src=\"images/drag_icon1.png\" alt=\"\"></span></div><h2><input name=\"\" id=\"text_"+ start+"\" onkeyup=\" text_boxes['text_" + start+ "']=this.value;\" onfocus=\"clear_default(this,default_title); \" onblur=\"add_default(this,default_title); \" type=\"text\" value=\"Title goes here\" class=\"list_box_input\"><br /><input name=\"\" id=\"text_sub_"+ start+"\" onkeyup=\" text_boxes['text_sub_" + start+ "']=this.value;\" onfocus=\"clear_default(this,default_subtitle); \" onblur=\"add_default(this,default_subtitle); \" type=\"text\" value=\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\" class=\"list_box_input2\"></h2><div class=\"list_box_img\"><h2>Add Content<br><span>Click the Edit button below.</span</h2></div><div class=\"list_box_icon2\"><div class=\"list_box_inn\"><a class=\"fancybox\" href=\"images/lighboxt_img.jpg\" data-fancybox-group=\"gallery\" title=\"Rules to Solve Proportions\"><div class=\"list_box_2\"><img src=\"images/box_icon1.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><a href=\"javascript:;\" onClick=\"hideblocks('outhide" + start+ "')\"><div class=\"delete_box_3\"><img src=\"images/delete_icon.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><div class=\"list_box_3\"><div class=\"box_message\">2</div><img src=\"images/box_icon2.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_4\"><div class=\"box_message\">1</div><img src=\"images/box_icon3.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_5\"><img src=\"images/box_icon4.png\" alt=\"\"></div></div></div></div></div></div>");
                    $("#droppable").append('<li id="li_' + li_ids_to_start_from +'"></li>');
                    li_ids_to_start_from++;
                    $('#droppable li').sortable({});
                    handle_drop();              

                }else if(ui.draggable.attr("class") =="letmego2 ui-draggable"){
                    $(this).html("<div  id=\"outhide2"+ start+"\"><div class=\"drag_icon_out\"><div class=\"list_box\"><div class=\"cam_out2\"><span><img src=\"images/drag_icon2.png\" alt=\"\"></span></div><h2><input name=\"\" id=\"text_"+ start+"\" onkeyup=\" text_boxes['text_" + start+ "']=this.value;\"  onfocus=\"clear_default(this,default_title); \" onblur=\"add_default(this,default_title); \" type=\"text\" value=\"Title goes here\" class=\"list_box_input\"><br /><input name=\"\"  id=\"text_sub_"+ start+"\" onkeyup=\" text_boxes['text_sub_" + start+ "']=this.value;\" onfocus=\"clear_default(this,default_subtitle); \" onblur=\"add_default(this,default_subtitle); \" type=\"text\" value=\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\" class=\"list_box_input2\"></h2><div class=\"list_box_img2\"><h2>Add Content<br><span>Click the Edit button below.</span</h2></div><div class=\"list_box_icon2\"><div class=\"list_box_inn\"><a class=\"fancybox\" href=\"images/lighboxt_img2.jpg\" data-fancybox-group=\"gallery\" title=\"Rules to Solve Proportions2\"><div class=\"list_box_2\"><img src=\"images/box_icon1.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><a href=\"javascript:;\" onClick=\"hideblocks('outhide2" + start+ "')\"><div class=\"delete_box_3\"><img src=\"images/delete_icon.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><div class=\"list_box_3\"><div class=\"box_message\">2</div><img src=\"images/box_icon2.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_4\"><div class=\"box_message\">1</div><img src=\"images/box_icon3.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_5\"><img src=\"images/box_icon4.png\" alt=\"\"></div></div></div></div></div></div>");
                    $("#droppable").append('<li id="li_' + li_ids_to_start_from +'"></li>');
                    li_ids_to_start_from++;
                    $('#droppable li').sortable({});
                    handle_drop();              

                }else if(ui.draggable.attr("class") =="letmego3 ui-draggable"){
                    $(this).html("<div  id=\"outhide3"+ start+"\"><div class=\"drag_icon_out\"><div class=\"list_box\"><div class=\"cam_out23\"><span><img src=\"images/drag_icon32.png\" alt=\"\"></span></div><h2><input name=\"\" id=\"text_"+ start+"\" onkeyup=\" text_boxes['text_" + start+ "']=this.value;\"  onfocus=\"clear_default(this,default_title); \" onblur=\"add_default(this,default_title); \" type=\"text\" value=\"Title goes here\" class=\"list_box_input\"><br /><input name=\"\"  id=\"text_sub_"+ start+"\" onkeyup=\" text_boxes['text_sub_" + start+ "']=this.value;\" onfocus=\"clear_default(this,default_subtitle); \" onblur=\"add_default(this,default_subtitle); \" type=\"text\" value=\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\" class=\"list_box_input2\"></h2><div class=\"list_box_img3\"><h2>Add Content<br><span>Click the Edit button below.</span</h2></div><div class=\"list_box_icon2\"><div class=\"list_box_inn\"><a class=\"fancybox\" href=\"images/lighboxt_img3.jpg\" data-fancybox-group=\"gallery\" title=\"Rules to Solve Proportions3\"><div class=\"list_box_2\"><img src=\"images/box_icon1.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><a href=\"javascript:;\" onClick=\"hideblocks('outhide3" + start+ "')\"><div class=\"delete_box_3\"><img src=\"images/delete_icon.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><div class=\"list_box_3\"><div class=\"box_message\">2</div><img src=\"images/box_icon2.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_4\"><div class=\"box_message\">1</div><img src=\"images/box_icon3.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_5\"><img src=\"images/box_icon4.png\" alt=\"\"></div></div></div></div></div></div>");
                    $("#droppable").append('<li id="li_' + li_ids_to_start_from +'"></li>');
                    li_ids_to_start_from++;
                    $('#droppable li').sortable({});
                    handle_drop();              

                }else if(ui.draggable.attr("class") =="letmego4 ui-draggable"){
                    $(this).html("<div  id=\"outhide4"+ start+"\"><div class=\"drag_icon_out\"><div class=\"list_box\"><div class=\"cam_out3\"><span><img src=\"images/drag_icon4.png\" alt=\"\"></span></div><h2><input name=\"\" id=\"text_"+ start+"\" onkeyup=\" text_boxes['text_" + start+ "']=this.value;\"  onfocus=\"clear_default(this,default_title); \" onblur=\"add_default(this,default_title); \" type=\"text\" value=\"Title goes here\" class=\"list_box_input\"><br /><input name=\"\"  id=\"text_sub_"+ start+"\" onkeyup=\" text_boxes['text_sub_" + start+ "']=this.value;\" onfocus=\"clear_default(this,default_subtitle); \" onblur=\"add_default(this,default_subtitle); \" type=\"text\" value=\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\" class=\"list_box_input2\"></h2><div class=\"list_box_img4\"><h2>Add Content<br><span>Click the Edit button below.</span</h2></div><div class=\"list_box_icon2\"><div class=\"list_box_inn\"><a class=\"fancybox\" href=\"images/lighboxt_img4.jpg\" data-fancybox-group=\"gallery\" title=\"Rules to Solve Proportions4\"><div class=\"list_box_2\"><img src=\"images/box_icon1.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><a href=\"javascript:;\" onClick=\"hideblocks('outhide4" + start+ "')\"><div class=\"delete_box_3\"><img src=\"images/delete_icon.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><div class=\"list_box_3\"><div class=\"box_message\">2</div><img src=\"images/box_icon2.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_4\"><div class=\"box_message\">1</div><img src=\"images/box_icon3.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_5\"><img src=\"images/box_icon4.png\" alt=\"\"></div></div></div></div></div></div>");
                    $("#droppable").append('<li id="li_' + li_ids_to_start_from +'"></li>');
                    li_ids_to_start_from++;
                    handle_drop();              

                }else if(ui.draggable.attr("class") =="letmego5 ui-draggable"){
                    $(this).html("<div id=\"outhide5"+ start+"\"><div class=\"drag_icon_out\"><div class=\"list_box\"><div class=\"cam_out4\"><span><img src=\"images/drag_icon5.png\" alt=\"\"></span></div><h2><input name=\"\" id=\"text_"+ start+"\" onkeyup=\" text_boxes['text_" + start+ "']=this.value;\"  onfocus=\"clear_default(this,default_title); \" onblur=\"add_default(this,default_title); \" type=\"text\" value=\"Title goes here\" class=\"list_box_input\"><br /><input name=\"\"  id=\"text_sub_"+ start+"\" onkeyup=\" text_boxes['text_sub_" + start+ "']=this.value;\" onfocus=\"clear_default(this,default_subtitle); \" onblur=\"add_default(this,default_subtitle); \" type=\"text\" value=\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\" class=\"list_box_input2\"></h2><div class=\"list_box_img5\"><h2>Add Content<br><span>Click the Edit button below.</span</h2></div><div class=\"list_box_icon2\"><div class=\"list_box_inn\"><a class=\"fancybox\" href=\"images/lighboxt_img5.jpg\" data-fancybox-group=\"gallery\" title=\"Rules to Solve Proportions\"><div class=\"list_box_2\"><img src=\"images/box_icon1.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><a href=\"javascript:;\" onClick=\"hideblocks('outhide5" + start+ "')\"><div class=\"delete_box_3\"><img src=\"images/delete_icon.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><div class=\"list_box_3\"><div class=\"box_message\">2</div><img src=\"images/box_icon2.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_4\"><div class=\"box_message\">1</div><img src=\"images/box_icon3.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_5\"><img src=\"images/box_icon4.png\" alt=\"\"></div></div></div></div></div></div>");
                    $("#droppable").append('<li id="li_' + li_ids_to_start_from +'"></li>');
                    li_ids_to_start_from++;
                    $('#droppable li').sortable({});
                    handle_drop();              

                }else if(ui.draggable.attr("class") =="letmego6 ui-draggable"){
                    $(this).html("<div  id=\"outhide6"+ start+"\"><div class=\"drag_icon_out\"><div class=\"list_box\"><div class=\"cam_out5\"><span><img src=\"images/drag_icon62.png\" alt=\"\"></span></div><h2><input name=\"\" id=\"text_"+ start+"\" onkeyup=\" text_boxes['text_" + start+ "']=this.value;\"  onfocus=\"clear_default(this,default_title); \" onblur=\"add_default(this,default_title); \" type=\"text\" value=\"Title goes here\" class=\"list_box_input\"><br /><input name=\"\"  id=\"text_sub_"+ start+"\" onkeyup=\" text_boxes['text_sub_" + start+ "']=this.value;\" onfocus=\"clear_default(this,default_subtitle); \" onblur=\"add_default(this,default_subtitle); \" type=\"text\" value=\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\" class=\"list_box_input2\"></h2><div class=\"list_box_img6\"><h2>Add Content<br><span>Click the Edit button below.</span</h2></div><div class=\"list_box_icon2\"><div class=\"list_box_inn\"><a class=\"fancybox\" href=\"images/lighboxt_img6.jpg\" data-fancybox-group=\"gallery\" title=\"Rules to Solve Proportions5\"><div class=\"list_box_2\"><img src=\"images/box_icon1.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><a href=\"javascript:;\" onClick=\"hideblocks('outhide6" + start+ "')\"><div class=\"delete_box_3\"><img src=\"images/delete_icon.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><div class=\"list_box_3\"><div class=\"box_message\">2</div><img src=\"images/box_icon2.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_4\"><div class=\"box_message\">1</div><img src=\"images/box_icon3.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_5\"><img src=\"images/box_icon4.png\" alt=\"\"></div></div></div></div></div></div>");
                    $("#droppable").append('<li id="li_' + li_ids_to_start_from +'"></li>');
                    li_ids_to_start_from++;
                    $('#droppable li').sortable({});
                    handle_drop();              

                }else if(ui.draggable.attr("class") =="letmego7 ui-draggable"){
                    $(this).html("<div  id=\"outhide7"+ start+"\"><div class=\"drag_icon_out\"><div class=\"list_box\"><div class=\"cam_out6\"><span><img src=\"images/drag_icon7.png\" alt=\"\"></span></div><h2><input name=\"\" id=\"text_"+ start+"\" onkeyup=\" text_boxes['text_" + start+ "']=this.value;\"  onfocus=\"clear_default(this,default_title); \" onblur=\"add_default(this,default_title); \" type=\"text\" value=\"Title goes here\" class=\"list_box_input\"><br /><input name=\"\"  id=\"text_sub_"+ start+"\" onkeyup=\" text_boxes['text_sub_" + start+ "']=this.value;\" onfocus=\"clear_default(this,default_subtitle); \" onblur=\"add_default(this,default_subtitle); \" type=\"text\" value=\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\" class=\"list_box_input2\"></h2><div class=\"list_box_img7\"><h2>Add Content<br><span>Click the Edit button below.</span</h2></div><div class=\"list_box_icon2\"><div class=\"list_box_inn\"><a class=\"fancybox\" href=\"images/lighboxt_img7.jpg\" data-fancybox-group=\"gallery\" title=\"Rules to Solve Proportions6\"><div class=\"list_box_2\"><img src=\"images/box_icon1.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><a href=\"javascript:;\" onClick=\"hideblocks('outhide7" + start+ "')\"><div class=\"delete_box_3\"><img src=\"images/delete_icon.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><div class=\"list_box_3\"><div class=\"box_message\">2</div><img src=\"images/box_icon2.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_4\"><div class=\"box_message\">1</div><img src=\"images/box_icon3.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_5\"><img src=\"images/box_icon4.png\" alt=\"\"></div></div></div></div></div></div>");
                    $("#droppable").append('<li id="li_' + li_ids_to_start_from +'"></li>');
                    li_ids_to_start_from++;
                    $('#droppable li').sortable({});
                    handle_drop();              

                }else if(ui.draggable.attr("class") =="letmego8 ui-draggable"){
                    $(this).html("<div  id=\"outhide8"+ start+"\"><div class=\"drag_icon_out\"><div class=\"list_box\"><div class=\"cam_out7\"><span><img src=\"images/drag_icon8.png\" alt=\"\"></span></div><h2><input name=\"\" id=\"text_"+ start+"\" onkeyup=\" text_boxes['text_" + start+ "']=this.value;\"  onfocus=\"clear_default(this,default_title); \" onblur=\"add_default(this,default_title); \" type=\"text\" value=\"Title goes here\" class=\"list_box_input\"><br /><input name=\"\"  id=\"text_sub_"+ start+"\" onkeyup=\" text_boxes['text_sub_" + start+ "']=this.value;\" onfocus=\"clear_default(this,default_subtitle); \" onblur=\"add_default(this,default_subtitle); \" type=\"text\" value=\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\" class=\"list_box_input2\"></h2><div class=\"list_box_img8\"><h2>Add Content<br><span>Click the Edit button below.</span</h2></div><div class=\"list_box_icon2\"><div class=\"list_box_inn\"><a class=\"fancybox\" href=\"images/lighboxt_img8.jpg\" data-fancybox-group=\"gallery\" title=\"Rules to Solve Proportions7\"><div class=\"list_box_2\"><img src=\"images/box_icon1.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><a href=\"javascript:;\" onClick=\"hideblocks('outhide8" + start+ "')\"><div class=\"delete_box_3\"><img src=\"images/delete_icon.png\" alt=\"\"></div></a><div class=\"list_box_3\"><div class=\"box_message\">2</div><img src=\"images/box_icon2.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_4\"><div class=\"box_message\">1</div><img src=\"images/box_icon3.png\" alt=\"\"></div><div class=\"list_box_5\"><img src=\"images/box_icon4.png\" alt=\"\"></div></div></div></div></div></div>");
                    $("#droppable").append('<li id="li_' + li_ids_to_start_from +'"></li>');
                    li_ids_to_start_from++;
                    $('#droppable li').sortable({});
                    handle_drop();              
                }

                answers = answers + 1;
            }



            $(this).children(":first").attr('style','');


            for(i=1;i <= start;i++){

                if(typeof text_boxes['text_' + i] === "undefined"){
                    $("#text_" + i).val(default_title);
                }else{
                    $("#text_" + i).val(text_boxes['text_' + i]);
                }   

                if(typeof text_boxes['text_sub_' + i] === "undefined"){
                    $("#text_sub_" + i).val(default_subtitle);
                }else{
                    $("#text_sub_" + i).val(text_boxes['text_sub_' + i]);
                }   

            }



            for(i=1;i < li_ids_to_start_from -1;i++){
                if($('#li_' + i).html() ==''){
                    $('#li_' + i).remove();
                }
            }




            if(!$("#droppable li:last-child").html() ==''){
                $("#droppable").append('<li id="li_' + li_ids_to_start_from +'"></li>');
                li_ids_to_start_from++;
                $('#droppable li').sortable({});
                handle_drop();

            }

            start++;
        }
    });
}

handle_drop();

    });



        $(function(){
$('#droppable').sortable({});
   });
```

Comment: Hey I couldn't understand your question. Could you please tried to write it more accurate?

Comment: problem is when i drag and drop in lists and sorting(moving) lists with each other it can automatically makes a new list of element..... i also want when i fill some numeric in title of list element and then sort with each others it can work into reverse order