# Date Format can change when Getting values from database

Tags: php

in daytabase date format is ->  2013-12-12 11:06:07

i want to change in this format by geting value from database ->  Thu Nov-28-13 10:02:56

```
<div class="time_lft_con">
     Time Left:  <span><!--3h 3m--></span> <!--(Thu Nov-28-13 10:02:56 EST)-->( <?php $get_date=$row['end_date']; ?> EST )
     <p>
       <a href="#">
          <img src="images/paypal_card_img.png" alt="" >
       </a>
     </p>
</div>
<?php echo date_format($get_date, 'Y-m-d H:i(worry)'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) in php

```
 <?php
    $date1="2013-12-12 11:06:07";
    $date = new DateTime($date1);
    echo $date->format('D M -d-y H:i:s');
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675741/automatically-new-list-can-generated-while-sorting-the-lists-with-numbering?noredirect=1#comment32765412_21675741
can u give me this ques answer also

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your question is, you should add some details. For what I understand you're looking for something like this :

```
<?php echo date_format($get_date, 'D M-d-y H:i:s'); ?>
```

You can find documentation here : http://fr.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php